# How do I implement this comparator?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, comparator

This is my code for a JTable. When I sort the numerical columns, it sorts it incorrectly. I would like to change this. The problem can be seen below in the screen shots.

[image: Number column sorted]
[image: Time column sorted]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
///////////
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.Document;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class JtableIe
{
    JFrame myMainWindow = new JFrame("Compare Tables");

    JPanel  firstPanel = new JPanel();

    JScrollPane myScrollTable;
    JTable myTable;
    JTextField srchFld1;
    JTextField srchFld2;
    TableRowSorter sorter;
    JLabel srchLbl1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel srchLbl2 = new JLabel();

    public void runGUI()
    {
        myMainWindow.setBounds(10, 10, 1296, 756);

        myMainWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        myMainWindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        createFirstPanel();

        myMainWindow.getContentPane().add(firstPanel);

        myMainWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createFirstPanel()
    {
        firstPanel.setLayout(null);

        srchLbl1.setLocation(0,0);
        srchLbl1.setSize(150,26);
        srchLbl1.setText("Name Search:");
        firstPanel.add(srchLbl1);

        srchLbl2.setLocation(660,0);
        srchLbl2.setSize(150,26);
        srchLbl2.setText("ID Search:");
        firstPanel.add(srchLbl2);

        String[] aHeaders = {"Name","ID","Number 1","Number 2","Time"};
        String[][] aData = new String[15][5];
        myTable = new JTable(aData,aHeaders);
        ///////Data////////
        aData[0][0] = "John";
        aData[0][3] = "JS96";
        aData[0][2] = "1";
        aData[0][3] = "186";
        aData[0][4] = "1h 23m";

        aData[1][0] = "David";
        aData[1][4] = "DB36";
        aData[1][2] = "2";
        aData[1][3] = "111852";
        aData[1][4] = "2h 55m";

        aData[2][0] = "Daniel";
        aData[2][5] = "DK73";
        aData[2][2] = "3";
        aData[2][3] = "2921";
        aData[2][4] = "1h 55m";

        aData[3][0] = "Janis";
        aData[3][6] = "JW84";
        aData[3][2] = "4";
        aData[3][3] = "6512";
        aData[3][4] = "12h 26m";

        aData[4][0] = "Adam";
        aData[4][7] = "AF98";
        aData[4][2] = "5";
        aData[4][3] = "7524";
        aData[4][4] = "5h 47m";

        aData[5][0] = "Matthew";
        aData[5][8] = "MB55";
        aData[5][2] = "6";
        aData[5][3] = "4989";
        aData[5][4] = "80h 30m";

        aData[6][0] = "Lewis";
        aData[6][9] = "LS23";
        aData[6][2] = "7";
        aData[6][3] = "56321";
        aData[6][4] = "880h 20m";

        aData[7][0] = "Mark";
        aData[7][10] = "ML49";
        aData[7][2] = "8";
        aData[7][3] = "97456";
        aData[7][4] = "8h 42m";

        aData[8][0] = "Josh";
        aData[8][11] = "JT67";
        aData[8][2] = "9";
        aData[8][3] = "82135";
        aData[8][4] = "56h 13m";

        aData[9][0] = "Oliver";
        aData[9][12] = "OC98";
        aData[9][2] = "10";
        aData[9][3] = "152";
        aData[9][4] = "9h 9m";

        aData[10][0] = "Tom";
        aData[10][13] = "TS97";
        aData[10][2] = "11";
        aData[10][3] = "100";
        aData[10][4] = "0m";

        aData[11][0] = "Emma";
        aData[11][14] = "EBS74";
        aData[11][2] = "12";
        aData[11][3] = "200";
        aData[11][4] = "30m";

        aData[12][0] = "Lucy";
        aData[12][15] = "LK02";
        aData[12][2] = "13";
        aData[12][3] = "256";
        aData[12][4] = "7h";

        aData[13][0] = "Patrick";
        aData[13][16] = "PM38";
        aData[13][2] = "14";
        aData[13][3] = "258";
        aData[13][4] = "2h";

        aData[14][0] = "Nicola";
        aData[14][17] = "NB70";
        aData[14][2] = "15";
        aData[14][3] = "987";
        aData[14][4] = "100h 56m";
        //////////////

        myTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);

        sorter = new TableRowSorter(myTable.getModel());
        List sortKeys = new ArrayList();
        sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
        sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
        myTable.setRowSorter(sorter);

        myScrollTable = new JScrollPane(myTable); 
        myScrollTable.setSize(1296,756); 
        myScrollTable.setLocation(0,25); 
        System.out.println("Creating compare table");

        srchFld1 = new JTextField(10);
        srchFld1.setSize(550,26); 
        srchFld1.setLocation(100,0);
        srchFld1.setToolTipText("Enter Name");
        firstPanel.add(srchFld1);

        srchFld2 = new JTextField(10);
        srchFld2.setSize(550,26); 
        srchFld2.setLocation(740,0);
        srchFld2.setToolTipText("Enter ID");
        firstPanel.add(srchFld2);

        //////////////////////
        Document doc = srchFld1.getDocument();
        DocumentListener listener = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }
        };
        doc.addDocumentListener(listener);

        ///////////////
        Document docb = srchFld2.getDocument();
        DocumentListener listenerb = new DocumentListener() {

            @Override
            public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }

            @Override
            public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
            {
                newFilter();
            }
        };
        docb.addDocumentListener(listenerb);
        ///////////////

        firstPanel.add(myScrollTable);
    }

    private void newFilter()
    {
        RowFilter rf = null;
        try 
        {
            List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(srchFld1.getText(), 0));
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(srchFld2.getText(), 1));
            rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
        } 
        catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) 
        {
            return;
        }
        sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JtableIe ji = new JtableIe();
        ji.runGUI();
    }
}
```

I have been told I can use this comparator to fix this problem, however I don't know how to implement it properly to work with my code.

```
import java.util.Comparator;


public class AlphanumComparator implements Comparator
{
private final boolean isDigit(char ch)
{
    return ch >= 48 && ch <= 57;
}

/** Length of string is passed in for improved efficiency (only need to calculate it once) **/
private final String getChunk(String s, int slength, int marker)
{
    StringBuilder chunk = new StringBuilder();
    char c = s.charAt(marker);
    chunk.append(c);
    marker++;
    if (isDigit(c))
    {
        while (marker < slength)
        {
            c = s.charAt(marker);
            if (!isDigit(c))
                break;
            chunk.append(c);
            marker++;
        }
    } else
    {
        while (marker < slength)
        {
            c = s.charAt(marker);
            if (isDigit(c))
                break;
            chunk.append(c);
            marker++;
        }
    }
    return chunk.toString();
}

public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
{
    if (!(o1 instanceof String) || !(o2 instanceof String))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    String s1 = (String)o1;
    String s2 = (String)o2;

    int thisMarker = 0;
    int thatMarker = 0;
    int s1Length = s1.length();
    int s2Length = s2.length();

    while (thisMarker < s1Length && thatMarker < s2Length)
    {
        String thisChunk = getChunk(s1, s1Length, thisMarker);
        thisMarker += thisChunk.length();

        String thatChunk = getChunk(s2, s2Length, thatMarker);
        thatMarker += thatChunk.length();

        // If both chunks contain numeric characters, sort them numerically
        int result = 0;
        if (isDigit(thisChunk.charAt(0)) && isDigit(thatChunk.charAt(0)))
        {
            // Simple chunk comparison by length.
            int thisChunkLength = thisChunk.length();
            result = thisChunkLength - thatChunk.length();
            // If equal, the first different number counts
            if (result == 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < thisChunkLength; i++)
                {
                    result = thisChunk.charAt(i) - thatChunk.charAt(i);
                    if (result != 0)
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                }
            }
        } else
        {
            result = thisChunk.compareTo(thatChunk);
        }

        if (result != 0)
            return result;
    }

    return s1Length - s2Length;
}
}
```

I would appreciate any help with implementing this. Thank you.

Comment: I am a novice programmer and don't know much about it. I would greatly appreciate a clear answer

Comment: Convert the values to a numeric value first...

Comment: ... as in: you are currently sorting alphanumerical (like a phone book does)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I was told to use this comparator by someone else on this website in a different question since it did alphanumerical sorting as shown by the website http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Comment: http://www.davekoelle.com/files/AlphanumComparator.java (code)

Comment: use the java.time package (i think you need Duration, but thats a bit depending upon what units you need)

Comment: I think my problem is that I don't know how to put this comparator in my code. I would appreciate someone showing me how to so I can do it the next time I need to use a comparator

Comment: You mean something like [Sorting and filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I have looked at that previously but I would like to be able to see an example of it because that is only a snippet of code and it doesn't show how it works in or effects the program

Comment: You know, I get really turned off by people who can't make a little effort to try something with the information at hand.  I respect that you've probably spent some time trying to get this to work and are probably frustrated, but it will be very rare that you will find the exact information you need to solve your exact problem and you need to be prepared to research and try different things.  When people simply say "give me the code", I'm highly tempted to simply close the tab and walk away...but's that's just me

Comment: Especially when you consider the quantity of [available information on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+jtable+comparator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As highlighted in [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultRowSorter.html) you could simply try using something like:

```
JTable myTable = null;

DefaultRowSorter sorter = (DefaultRowSorter) myTable.getRowSorter();
sorter.setComparator(2, new AlphanumComparator());
```